# how to use for loop for multiple inputs

Tags: python, for-loop

This is my code where I want to apply the for loop to check the best values result.   I want to apply the for loop for num_ants = 1000 , so I want to test the best values for the values 500,600, 700, 800,900  and like this for other inputs.

```
 num_ants = int(input("Please enter the number of ants (1000 recommended): "))
    if num_ants <= 0:
        quit("value entered for number of ants is non-positive")


min_cases_per_rule = int(input("Please enter the minimum number of cases per rule (10 recommended): "))
if min_cases_per_rule <= 0:
    quit("value entered for minimum number of cases per rule is non-positive")



max_uncovered_cases = int(input("Please enter the maximum number of uncovered cases in the training set (10 recommended): "))
if max_uncovered_cases < 0:
    quit("value entered for maximum number of uncovered cases is non-zero")




num_rules_converge = int(input("Please enter the number of rules used to test convergence of the ants (40 recommended): ")) #10
if num_rules_converge <= 0:
    quit("value entered for number of rules used to test convergence of the ants is non-positive")
```

Comment: Was there any problem when you tried to write a `for` loop?

Comment: I want to apply the for loop for the values to check the best values combination.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:  

        num_ants = int(input("Please enter the number of ants (1000 recommended): "))
        if num_ants <= 0:
            quit("value entered for number of ants is non-positive")


        min_cases_per_rule = int(input("Please enter the minimum number of cases per rule (10 recommended): "))
        if min_cases_per_rule <= 0:
            quit("value entered for minimum number of cases per rule is non-positive")


        max_uncovered_cases = int(input("Please enter the maximum number of uncovered cases in the training set (10 recommended): "))
        if max_uncovered_cases < 0:
            quit("value entered for maximum number of uncovered cases is non-zero")


        num_rules_converge = int(input("Please enter the number of rules used to test convergence of the ants (40 recommended): ")) #10
        if num_rules_converge <= 0:
            quit("value entered for number of rules used to test convergence of the ants is non-positive")

        # do your calculations and give results

        keep_going = input('Try another set of parameters? Type "no" to exit.')
        if keep_going == "no":
            break
```

Comment: I want to check the best values for these multiple input values. I want to use for loop to check which value is best.